# Scoring algorithm given attributes and weights

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

How would I go about coming up with an effective way to score something given known values and weights.

For example, I'm trying to score a machine with fitness value and I first want to take into account cpu usage.
CPU is weighted lets say 50 out of 100. (50% importance)
I know the average cpu. (avg_cpu)
I know the current ratio change in cpu (delta) or (cpu/average_cpu)

We know that constant low cpu is good.
We know that constant low cpu with some spikes is ok.
We know that constant high cpu is eh. (Could be just how that machine runs)
We know that constant low cpu then all of a sudden constant constant high cpu is bad.

I'd like the final score of cpu to be out 100.

Given this criteria how do I go about coming up with an effective algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try [linear regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) by fitting a linear equation to the dataset which already you have given scores by hand . Use MATLAB or R to get inbuilt functions for linear regression. Once you have the equation you can directly give the input parameters and get the output values.

**Caution :-**

Wont work if your function is non linear but you always use more complex methods like [SVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine)